# C# How do I prevent a file from saving without the asked extension?

Tags: c#

I'm currently writing a program and using my own file extension ".pn" for these files. When I use the `BinaryWriter` in `FileMode.Create` to write to the file "primes.pn" and then look in the file explorer it does not have the extension I asked. My file explorer has display file extensions turned on. How could I prevent this from happening/what is causing this?

Additionally the check for whether "primes.pn" exists passes but then when checking the length of the file it throws a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`.

```cs
if (!File.Exists("res_divisibility/primes.pn") && bytes.Count > new FileInfo("res_divisibility/primes.pn").Length)
{
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream("res_divisibility/primes.pn", FileMode.Create));
    foreach(byte b in bytes)
        bw.Write(b);
}
```

Comment: What OS are you running this on? Works fine on Windows. What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @DanielMann This is on Windows and .Net Core 3.1

Comment: File Explorer presents you a *view*.  Showing file extensions is often turned off.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I specified that file extensions are turned on.

Comment: I *strongly* suspect that you're either looking in the wrong place or something similar. I have never, *ever* seen the `FileStream` constructor use the wrong filename. I'd also note that `File.WriteAllBytes` is a rather simpler way of doing this than writing each byte individually.

Comment: Your current code only checks the file length if the file *doesn't* exist. That's a bug... I suspect you meant to use `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: And don't use BinaryWriter.  Just use `Stream.Write(bytes)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.write?view=net-6.0

Comment: @JonSkeet `File.WriteAllBytes` does not seem to cause this problem. The check was indeed my mistake. Still curious about what was causing the first problem tho.

Comment: I strongly suspect that `new FileStream` doesn't *actually* cause this problem either, and you were just misdiagnosing it. If you still believe the `FileStream` constructor *does* cause the problem, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure what was causing the problem but `File.WriteAllBytes()`solves this issue. The existence check was my mistake because I was using `&&` instead of `||`.